# Pregunta: ¿Cómo pasar datos entre tablas HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Supongamos que  por medio de dos botónes,se puedan pasar los datos entre tablas, es decir mover un registro o fila de la primer tabla a la segunda tabla o viceversa.

¿Saben si existe un ejemplo de estas tablas pero en codigo HTML y Javascript/Jquery? y ¿Como se llama dicha función (si se le podría llamar así)?

Comment: Pues yo creería que para hacer eso necesitas algo de JavaScript.

Comment: ¿Pero en si sabes como se llaman? o ¿tiene un ejemplo que pueda encontrar?

Comment: No existe una solución "presiona este botón para pasar tus datos a otra tabla". Tal vez si buscas como desplazar elementos del DOM, encuentres soluciones que te hagan el trabajo en muy buena parte.

Comment: De hecho me equivoque en mi pregunta, deje lo edito por que no es con uno es con dos botones, uno que tengan la flecha (<--) y en el otro botón    (-->)

Comment: Donde indiquen donde se dirigen los datos de la tabla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El unico modo que se me ocurre es identificar un row `<tr></tr>` de una tabla e insertarlo manualmente en otra.

```js
function move_row(){ 
  var row = $("#dummy1").detach();
  $("#table2").append(row);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2> Table 1 </h2>

<table id="table1" border=1>
  <tr id="dummy1">
    <td> 1 </td>
    <td> Text </td>
    <td> 100 </td>
  <tr>
  <tr id="dummy2">
    <td> 2 </td>
    <td> String </td>
    <td> 150 </td>
  <tr>
  <tr id="dummy3">
    <td> 3 </td>
    <td> Random </td>
    <td> 200 </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<a href="javascript:move_row()">Move</a>

<h2> Table 2 </h2>
<table id="table2" border=1> 
 
  <tr id="dummy4">
    <td> 4 </td>
    <td> Other </td>
    <td> 250 </td>
  </tr>
   
</table>
```